# Need to retrieve original validated object from MethodArgumentNotValidException

Tags: java, spring, validation, controller

I have a List with JSR Validations like @Max, @Min, and a Dto with inner list like:

```
"data": [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "age": 110, //@Max(100)
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "age": 200, //@Max(100)
}]
```

I want to handle JSR with `@ControllerAdvice` and overriding `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` method. If I try to inspect `BindingResult` instance I can get all errors but they are instances from `SpringValidatorAdapter.ViolationFieldError`

Inside this class, `ViolationFieldError`, there is a property named `violation` and inside this a `leafBeanInstance` with the original object from the list.

I cannot use this because, `ViolationFieldError` is a private class

How can I deal with this? Suggestions?

Thanks